# C++ class function name is changing because of a #define

Tags: c++, mingw

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    void GetForm() {}
};
```

Now I want to call `GetForm`:

```
MyClass myobj;
myobj.GetForm();
```

And at compilation I get this error:

```
error: 'class MyClass' has no member named 'GetFormA'; did you mean 'GetForm'?
```

What I have found is that in a file (`winspool.h`), there is a definition:

```
#define GetForm __MINGW_NAME_AW(GetForm)
```

And this results in `GetFormA` I guess for encoding thing.

But, how can it be possible that a `#define` replace in a name of a function of an object?

How can resolve this?

Comment: _"But, how can it be possible that a `#define` replace in a name of a function of an object?"_ Because the preprocessor is just a dumb text replacing tool more or less.

Comment: Oh, if you think this is wild, for a `#define`, then try this: `#define if while`.

Comment: Wow, I knew Winapi is weird, but this is a whole next level. You can try `#undef GetForm`, but I can't guarantee that it will not break some other things.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen In c++ the best option probably is to wrap the whole access to that module in proper template class interfaces. This would separate the plain WinAPI stuff from other (e.g. GUI) frameworks and classes.

Comment: Thank you @Yksisarvinen for suggesting a solution before attacking as if I was the one who put this macro.

Comment: @MertMertce Who attacked you because of that?

Comment: It is closed in seconds with a link that tells "Why are preprocessor macros evil?".
Good, macros are evil, and how does this answer the question? I have not created the macro. Should I modify winapi??

Comment: @MertMertce It's mentioned in the answers there, that you can `#undef` that macro, to not be applied to your code. Anoother alternative is to decouple that stuff completely using your own interface definitons.

Comment: Welcome to Windows. One possible solution is to put `#include <Windows.h>` in the header file as well as the source file. That way you get the same source-code stomping in both files.